# How to make canvas inside imageview respond to touch?

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, ontouch

I have a canvas inside an ImageView. How can I make it respond to touch? The end goal here is to be able to drag objects inside the canvas. I wonder if that is even possible. But for now, how can I just make it respond to touch? I have the following code and it doesn't do anything when I click inside the imageview (Although it does respond to the button). What am I doing wrong?

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements   View.OnTouchListener{

```
ImageView ourFrame;
Button ourButton;
Bitmap ourBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(700,700, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas ourCanvas = new Canvas(ourBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
Bitmap ball;
float x, y;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ourFrame = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
    ourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDrawLine);
    ourCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    ourFrame.setImageBitmap(ourBitmap);
    ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
    x = 0;
    y = 0;

    ourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            ourCanvas.drawLine(10, 50, 200, 50, paint);
            ourFrame.setImageBitmap(ourBitmap);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

    x = me.getX();
    y = me.getY();
    ourCanvas.drawBitmap(ball, x - (ball.getWidth() / 2), y - (ball.getHeight() / 2), null);
    ourFrame.setImageBitmap(ourBitmap);
    return true;
}
```

}